# How to add /*+Parallel*/ to a hibernate name query

Tags: spring, hibernate

I want to add a parallel hint to a hibernate name query.

I am running into performance issue where if the data is huge, my app is taking a lot of time running on server.

query is defined in hbm.xml

```
<query name="getResults">
    <![CDATA[           
    select /*+Parallel(16)*/ id from Table as table123
    where table123.column=123
    ]]>
</query>
```

Can anyone help me how to achieve it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried adding /*Parallel(16)*/ in hbm. But it is giving error on server startp. Unexpected syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any version of hibernate has a build in hints to support Parallel query. Have you tried it with native query? For example in JPA. I don't know what type of database you are using, you might need to use dialect matches your db type.

```
final String queryStr = "select /*+Parallel(16)*/ id from Table as table123
    where table123.column=123"
Query nativeQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryStr, Long.class);
List<Long> result = nativeQuery.getResultList();
```